# Numbers in ng-bind-html value changed to link

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-bind-html

html

```
<div class="col" ng-bind-html=" info.displayedName "> </div>
```

js

```
$scope.info.displayedName = "01023232323";
```

I used `ng-bind-html` to set content dynamically. It works but when the value contains numbers, it sometimes recognises it as a phone number and displays a link on my phone.

What should I do if I want to display plain text always?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col" ng-model="info.displayedName">{{info.displayedName}} </div>
```